# how to quickly create the nodes in neo4j with out provide the node ids?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j does not support the node id with the same name ,such as

```
    CREATE (p:Person { id:100001, firstname: 'John', surname: 'Wood', age: 25 })
    CREATE (p:Person { id:100002, firstname: 'Jack', surname: 'Wood', age: 35 })
    CREATE (p:Person { id:100003, firstname: 'John', surname: 'Wood', age: 45 })
    CREATE (p:Person { id:100004, firstname: 'Jack', surname: 'Wood', age: 55 })
```

The different ids must be provided,such as:

```
    CREATE (p100001:Person { id:100001, firstname: 'John', surname: 'Wood', age: 25 })
    CREATE (p100002:Person { id:100002, firstname: 'Jack', surname: 'Wood', age: 35 })
    CREATE (p100003:Person { id:100003, firstname: 'John', surname: 'Wood', age: 45 })
    CREATE (p100004:Person { id:100004, firstname: 'Jack', surname: 'Wood', age: 55 })
```

How to quickly create the nodes with out providing the ids?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes are automatically initialized with an internally-generated id property in Neo4J, available after creation by calling id(node).

While you might be able to technically get away with setting your own ID as you have above, my experience has been that it is better to renamed your property to something else, e.g personId.

To your question, you could use foreach to iterate over your source data and create the nodes without needing to declare unique variables (only two nodes created in this example for brevity):

```
foreach (person in [{firstName:'John', surname:'Wood', age:25}, {firstName:'Jack', surname:'Wood', age:35}] |
create (p:Person{name:person.name, age:person.age})
)
```

Comment: It's useful.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can try :

```
CREATE (:Person { id:100001, firstname: 'John', surname: 'Wood', age: 25 }),
    (:Person { id:100002, firstname: 'Jack', surname: 'Wood', age: 35 }), 
    (:Person { id:100003, firstname: 'John', surname: 'Wood', age: 45 }), 
    (:Person { id:100004, firstname: 'Jack', surname: 'Wood', age: 55 })
```